# How do I concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects?

Tags: python, string, concatenation

```
age = raw_input ('How old are you? ')
print "In two year's time you will be: " , age + 2
```

How do I get the last line of this code to work? I get the error `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects` when I run it in Python.

Comment: `age = int(raw_input('How old are you? '))` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use coerce the `int` to a `str` and use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to add it to your string:

```
age = int(raw_input ('How old are you? ')) 
print "In two year's time you will be: {}".format(age + 2)
```

Comment: This will still try to concatenate a string and an int.

Comment: OK, but `str.format` isn't actually necessary or relevant to this error, while your answer presents it as the solution.

Comment: It's the best practice way of interpolating variables into strings and is preferred to using `%` ( see the docs linked above for confirmation ). Given the that the heart of the op's question is string interpolation, adding the use of `format()` gives him best practice knowledge to use as his application becomes more complex.

Comment: It's fine to recommend the usage of `format`, in addition to explaining what the problem was. But having the entire text of your answer as "Use str.format" implies that not using it was the cause of the error, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

We can concatenate it by typecasting age to int and then adding it to an int.

```
 age = raw_input ('How old are you? ')
 print "In two year's time you will be: " , int(age) + 2
```

Infact a better way to print this would be to use format:

```
print "In two year's time you will be: {}".format(int(age) + 2)
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code? Please provide an explanation for the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
age = int(raw_input ('How old are you? '))
print "In two year's time you will be: " , age + 2
```

Comment: @interjay, yes, something stupid... the idea is that you have to make int() of your input first.

Answer (score 0):

```
age = raw_input ('How old are you? ')
print "In two year's time you will be: " , str(int(age) + 2)
```

That should work if you are using Python 2.7, not sure if it will work on 3.x